# Slickgrid filtering is crippled when CheckboxSelectColumn plugin is used

Tags: slickgrid

I have a slickgrid with 25,000+ rows. I have setup column filtering (see [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html)) which works fine and is very fast.

I have now added the `CheckboxSelectColumn` plugin (see [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html)) and while this worked it has crippled the speed of the filtering. Everything still works, just very much slower.

I have tried optimising the filtering by supplying `RefreshHints` (see [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html)) but no joy.

Is it just the combination of filtering plus checkboxes plus large row count, or am I doing something wrong?

Here are the relevant bits of code (CoffeeScript).

**Setup the Column Filters**

```
setupColumnFilters:()->
    $(grid.getHeaderRow()).delegate(':input', 'change keyup', (e) ->
        columnId = $(this).data('columnId')
        if columnId?
            newVal = $.trim($(this).val())
            columnFilters[columnId] = newVal

            # Trying to optimise using RefreshHints
            newLen = newVal?.length
            oldlen = columnFilters[columnId]?.length ? 0
            isNarrowing = newLen > oldlen
            isExpanding = newLen < oldlen
            renderedRange = grid.getRenderedRange()
            dataView.setRefreshHints({
                ignoreDiffsBefore: renderedRange.top,
                ignoreDiffsAfter: renderedRange.bottom + 1,
                isFilterNarrowing: isNarrowing,
                isFilterExpanding: isExpanding
            })
            dataView.refresh()
    )

    grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe((e, args) ->
        node = $(args.node)
        node.empty()
        id = args.column.id
        if id == '_checkbox_selector'
            node.hide()
            return
        placeholder = 'filter by ' + id
        html = '<input type="text" placeholder="' + placeholder + '">'
        $(html)
            .data('columnId', id)
            .val(columnFilters[id])
            .appendTo(node)
            .focus(()->$(this).attr('placeholder', ''))
            .blur(()-> $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholder) if $(this).val()?)
    )
```

**Setup the CheckboxSelect Plugin**

```
setupCheckboxSelect:() ->
    checkboxPlugin = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({ cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel" });
    columns.unshift(checkboxPlugin.getColumnDefinition());
    grid.setColumns(columns);
    grid.registerPlugin(checkboxPlugin);
```

**The Filter Function**

```
filter: (item) =>
    grid.setSelectedRows([])
    columns = grid.getColumns()
    for columnId, filter of columnFilters
        if filter?  
            column = columns[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)]
            field = item[column.field]
            return false unless (field? && field.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
    return true
```

Comment: Hard to say without debugging/profiling your code.  Can you post a repro on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, why are you calling `grid.setSelectedRows([])` in your filter?!?
It gets called 25'000 times whenever you refresh the data.

Besides being completely pointless, it does slow things down even more when you use the checkbox select column since it needs to synchronize the state (based on selection).

Comment: I did it because I am a bad, bad, bad coder <sob> - I admit it. Removing that putrid line has totally fixed my problem and also given my loading speed quite the performance boost. I am awash with gratitude. Now I just need to find a non-stupid way of correctly maintaining the selected rows when a filter is applied. You could complete my embarrassment by telling me there is a slick method to do just this.

Comment: DataView.syncGridSelection(grid, keepHiddenRows)